# Import Docx to Lyx no more possible?

Tags: lyx, msword, word-to-latex

I was used to import .docx files in LyX, but it seems that this functionality is no more possible on my version of LyX... Do you know if there's a canonical way to import a .doc document on LyX?

Comment: Do you have `pandoc` installed? Look here for more detailed information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ImportExport

Comment: I have pandoc installed, but it does not appear "Pandoc" as possibilities in the import menu... is it possible?

Comment: Install Pandoc and reconfigure LyX (tools menu). Even  if you cannot import from Word directly, you can export it to others formats than LyX can accept (.odt, for example). IMHO the best in work flow  is .docx → .md → .lyx (see [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ConvertMarkdown)) because it maintains the text structure but discards low formats for visual appearance (mostly garbage in most conversions with any format).

Comment: Thank you now it works